# How can I prevent the email subscribe box from opening, when someone hits enter on the search box?

Tags: css, themes

I have two forms on my [website](http://noahsdad.com/), a email sign up box, and a search box (both on the side bar.) I have a problem where if someone tries to press enter on the search box to preform a search of the site, it always opens up the email sign up form. In other words, the site search form will don't open.

I can't figure out how to fix this, any ideas?

Here's the code I'm using in the text widget to get the form to show up.

```
<div class="signupForm"><form action="http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify" method="post" target="popupwindow" onsubmit="window.open('http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/mailverify?uri=noahsdad', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');return true">
   <p>
       <input type="text" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your email address';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter your email address') {this.value = '';}" value="Enter your email address"/>
   </p>
   <input type="hidden" value="noahsdad" name="uri"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `</form>` tag for the first `<form>` element on your page (line 506).  The problem is caused because the two forms are seen as one, and hitting "enter" causes them both to submit.

If you split them up, each will be a different form, and then hitting "enter" will only submit the one the user is currently on.

Comment: I added the code, and it looks like I have a /form tag. Am I missing something?

Comment: I looked at the code for your web page, and ctl+f shows 3 `<form>` and only two `</form>`.  For proper HTML, you need a closing tag for every opening tag.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I pasted the code above, do I need to add a /form tag to that code? Or somewhere else?

Comment: thanks. I understand what a closing tag is, but my problem is I'm not sure where I missing it / where to add it.

Comment: Remember to properly close all of your HTML tags, otherwise the browser interpretation of the page will be unpredictable. If you use a plugins or third-party tools in your code always check for code errors at www.validator.w3.org/check

Comment: Ok, I think I fixed it. How does it look now?

Comment: No problem.  Have fun with fatherhood!

Comment: @SomeKittens Thanks. I will. :) (Now I've gotta try to figure out how to fix some of those erros that show up on that validator link.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the search form being nested in the email sign up form.

Forms shouldn't be nested in HTML.

You can verify this problem using the W3 Validator:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnoahsdad.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm not sure how this happend. They are both widgets. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

"Enter" key is the default submission key for any HTML form. In your case this happens, because you put the two fields in the same HTML form. Try to separate them. I don`t believe, that is necessary to use javascript code (although you can do that and not separate the forms) to catch the enter key pressing. The elegant solution is to use different forms,  because they will correspond to different actions.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I didn't put the same fields in the same form. They are two separate widgets. Am I missing something?

Comment: when you say use different forms, what do you mean? How would I go about doing that?